# Adding parameter to Altium library via Excel or script to entire library

Tags: altium

I have a library (Altium) of more than 30000 symbols (schematic).
I want to add 3 parameters (MFG, MFG_PN, and Digikey_PN) to the entire library.

How can this be done via script or any other possible way?

Comment: Excel is clearly not the right tool.

Comment: First of all you won't be using ALL of those symbols for your project, and second of all, there may be some common symbols for one component ... In other words, I think you're looking at doing something to 30000 symbols that may not be necessary and is actually an overkill. You might find it easier to add those 3 parameters on a one-by-one component, as required when you come across a component that you will actually use in a real circuit design ...